# Social sharing with custom text, url and image

Tags: php, facebook, meta, addthis, sharethis

My requirement is to share a URL/page that is accessible only after the login!! sounds weird and meaningless but that's the requirement!! The problem is I can not use Open graph because facebook, twitter, and other social media who use Open graph will always take the title, text, and image of the login page from the meta information. So I searched and googled to get a way around to share the private URL with custom text, image, and URL. I have created some POC and have followed some plugins but nothing is helping me out.

- I followed this article of "Share this":- https://www.sharethis.com/support/legacy/how-to-customize-which-url-text-and-img-to-share/ *( need to change button js to https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js )*

This option is working fine for email sharing but social media is fetching the Login page meta always.

- I followed this article for "Add this":- https://www.addthis.com/academy/setting-the-url-title-to-share/ *(this seems to be old and they don't specify the date of the article!! )*

This option is also not working and does not solve what is required.

So my question is it possible to share the page with custom title, image or description that is not accessible without login ?? if yes then any idea how to achieve this without Meta, Open graph, schema.org etc.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use OpenGraph tags on pages which require login. Facebook, Twitter and etc cannot access through obviously. Try to somehow recognize social media that request your protected content and give it to them.